# Either prove or disprove by counterexample $(A − B)^c = (A)^c − (B)^c$ and $A − B = (B)^c − (A)^c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

(a) $(A − B)^c = (A)^c − (B)^c$?

(b) $A − B = (B)^c − (A)^c$?

**For a)** I know that $(A − B)^c$ = $(A^c)^c$ = $A$ and $(A)^c − (B)^c$ = $(A^c)^c$ = $A$. So, they are equal.

**For b)** $A - B$ = $A^c$ and $(B)^c − (A)^c$ = $(B^c)^c$, which equals $B$

But I don't really know how to approach it from a proof standpoint. I could really use some help.

I am a rookie and trying to learn early as I would like to major in math someday, so thank you in advance.

Comment: What does $A-B$ mean? How do you know it is equal to $A^c$?

Comment: Study union, intersection, set difference, DeMorgan's law. Play with some small sets and try to see the bigger picture.

Comment: Oops, just realized my previous comment had a mistake. But still, there are a few mistakes you're making in the identities you list to justify (a) and (b). Where do you get the equality that $(A-B)^c=(A^c)^c$? Here is a counter example. Take the total set $U=\{1,2,3\}$. Let $A=U$ and $B=\{1\}$. Then $(A^c)^c=A=\{1,2,3\}$. But $A-B=\{2,3\}$ and so $(A-B)^c=\{1\}$. These are not equal.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I made a big mistake. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: $(A-B)^c$ is the set of all elements where it is not true that the element is both in A and not in B which means the element is either not in $A$ or it is in $B$.  Meanwhile $A^c -B^c$ is the set of all elements that both not in $A$ and is in $B$.  Are those sets the same?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to prove $b)$.

Note:  $x\in(A-B)\iff x\in A\land x\not\in B\iff x\in A\land x\in B^c\iff x\not\in A^c\land x\in B^c \iff x\in B^c-A^c$.

Now a counterexample for $a)$:

In $\Bbb Z$, let $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1\}$.

Then $(A-B)^c=\Bbb Z\setminus \{2\}$.

But $A^c-B^c=\emptyset$.

---

Note, once we have $b)$, we get that $a)$ would imply $(A-B)^c=(B^c-A^c)^c=(B^c)^c-(A^c)^c=B-A$.  So, for instance,  anytime $B$ is a proper subset of $A$ (and$A^c\not=\emptyset$), it doesn't work.